# My computer goes out of standby by itself

Tags: suspend, 18.04, power-management, bug-reporting

I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed, and when I close the cover of my computer to put it to sleep, it turns on all alone a few seconds later ... I always find it turned off the next day because the battery was emptied, and this also happens when I leave my computer connected to its charger.

Is it normal? And how can i fix this? Thank you for your help